# MySQL PDO: Using bound placeholder within a regular expression

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

Here's a PHP snippet attempting to fetch some rows from a MySQL table:

```
$connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,'dbcontext', PROJDBUSER, PROJDBPWD);
$sql= "SELECT contextleft, contextright 
       FROM tblcontext 
       WHERE contextleft REGEXP '[[:<:]]:word[[:>:]]' 
       LIMIT 0, 10";
$xleft = array();
$xright = array();
$countrows = 0;
$query = $connect->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':word', $term);
if($query->execute()) {
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $xleft[$countrows] = $row['contextleft'];
        $xright[$countrows] = $row['contextright'];
        $countrows++;
    }
    $notfound = null;
}
```

I reckon there's some problem with the following line in the above code:

```
$sql= "SELECT contextleft, contextright FROM tblcontext WHERE contextleft REGEXP '[[:<:]]:word[[:>:]]' LIMIT 0, 10";
```

Basically, I need to run a regex that matches a word (bound by the *:word* placeholder) and returns matching records. The code is otherwise fine because it works without the regex. But somehow it refuses to return anything when I use the regex. Is there something wrong with the way I have used the placeholder parameter within the regex?

In a nutshell, my question is how can one use a bound placeholder inside of a regular expression?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**: The table is named **tblcontext** with the following structure:

```
Engine MyISAM
sn: int(11), auto-increment, primary key
contextleft: varchar(190), fulltext index, unique
contextright: varchar(190), fulltext index, unique
```

Some random examples that should match when the user enters, say, *fly*:

```
I want to fly
To fly is easy
She will never fly because she is too heavy
```

Some random examples that should NOT match when the user enters *fly*:

```
Flying is easy
There is a blowfly on your food
She has been flying since last night
```

I cannot use FULLTEXT search for examples like the above because it only works for search strings larger than 3 characters.

Comment: Not sure if it's the only problem, but the inserted string is going to be quoted, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Probably: but if you checked the result of the `->prepare` and added a print of the error you could solve it yourself

Comment: I know it works when the actual value is used in the regex instead of a placeholder but like you said, that is not an option for me. Well, that will defeat the whole purpose of using PDO's binding feature and expose my table to injection, no?

Comment: Try making the bound parameter be the whole regex pattern, including the injected variable.  `$query->bindParam(':pattern, "[[:<:]]".$term."[[:>:]]");` and then `... contextleft REGEXP :pattern LIMIT ...`

Comment: This sounds like a brilliant idea, almost common-sense! Yet it failed to work. I tried this: `$word = "[[:<:]]".$term."[[:>:]]"; $query->bindParam(':word', $word);` instead of directly using the expression in *bindParam()*. Using it directly inside *bindParam()* gave some error which I am unable to see for some reason.

Comment: Define "it failed to work".  You got an error or you got an empty result set?  Also, can you provide an example search and an example string that you expect it to match?

Comment: When used via a variable ($word), it returned empty. When used directly, it throws an error and I, for the love of my life, haven't been able to see the actual error. I will update the question with a couple of example strings and table details.

Comment: @PatrickQ: Finally I got it to work. Don't know how but adding the `PDO::PARAM_STR` argument to `bindParam()` and using a separate variable did the trick. Like so: `$word = "[[:<:]]".$term."[[:>:]]"; $query->bindParam(':word', $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);`. Now could you post your comment incorporating this update as an answer so I could accept and close the thread?

Comment: hmmmm.... not sure why you needed to explicitly set the `PARAM_STR`, that's the default.  I'll write this up as an answer though.

Comment: It did not work the first way because variables are passed by reference to `bindParam`, so the second argument to `bindParam` must be a _variable_, not an _expression_. Including or excluding `PDO::PARAM_STR` should have no effect as that is the default value for that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify an unquoted data-type (such as `PDO::PARAM_INT`), then your injected string is going to be quoted.  Since you do not want to add quotes within your regex pattern (which is already encased in quotes), you need to put the entire pattern into your bound parameter.

```
$connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,'dbcontext', PROJDBUSER, PROJDBPWD);
$sql= "SELECT contextleft, contextright 
       FROM tblcontext 
       WHERE contextleft REGEXP :word
       LIMIT 0, 10";
$xleft = array();
$xright = array();
$countrows = 0;
$query = $connect->prepare($sql);
$word = "[[:<:]]".$term."[[:>:]]";
$query->bindParam(':word', $word, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if($query->execute()) {
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $xleft[$countrows] = $row['contextleft'];
        $xright[$countrows] = $row['contextright'];
        $countrows++;
    }
    $notfound = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you checked the result of the `$connect->prepare($sql);` and added a print of the error you could solve it yourself

```
$query = $connect->prepare($sql);
if ( $query === FALSE ) {
    print_r( $connect->error_info() );
    exit;
}
```

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

Comment: Strangely enough, `$query === FALSE` does not evaluate, `$query === TRUE` does.

Comment: See additional info, you really should set PDOExceptions on your connect? Or have you?

Comment: What I meant was PDO::Prepare() isn't returning FALSE which is why the if-then above isn't evaluating.

Comment: Well then it is not failing to prepare that query